# solve the following equation

Tags: functional-analysis

Please, help me with this. Let $(X,<,>)$, $u,v, w \in X-\{0\} $. Find the solution of the equation:
$$x+<x,u>w=v$$.
Would it be helpful to note by $\lambda=<x,u>$?the equation would become: $x+\lambda w=v$, $\lambda w=v-x$.And I dont know to continue from here..some suggestions, please?

Comment: Do you need to solve this for arbitrary inner product?

Comment: Yes, Kaster, for abrbitrary inner product.

Comment: Do you know anything about $u, v, w$? Like orthogonality, or linear dependence, etc?

Comment: Nothing..There are from the space $X$, that is all  what is given..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I'm gonna use dot product notation for inner product instead of angular brackets, because it's easier to type.

So, you have this equation
$$
x + (x \cdot u) w = v
$$
Now, multiply both side to $u$
$$
x \cdot u + (x \cdot u)(w \cdot u) = v \cdot u \implies (x \cdot u) \left ( 1 + w \cdot u \right) = v \cdot u \implies x \cdot u = \frac {v \cdot u}{1 + w \cdot u}
$$
Now, substitute it back to the initial equation
$$
x + \frac {v \cdot u}{1 + w \cdot u} w = v \implies x = v - \frac {v \cdot u}{1 + w \cdot u} w
$$

Comment: Thank you so, so much, Kaster!

Comment: @user308560 please mark it as a solution if it fully answers your question.

Comment: Ok,i did it, Kaster!